# How to build a document that is bigger than 1MB when using the search api?

Tags: google-app-engine

According to the [Search documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Quotas).  The maximum document size is 1MB.

So if I had a model whose TextProperty is unlimited length, how do I build a Document that could potentially be bigger than 1MB?

```
from google.appengine.api import search
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Note(ndb.Model):
  content = ndb.TextProperty()

def create_doc(note):
  return search.Document(fields=[search.TextField(name='note', value=note.content)])
```

Should I break up content in multiple 1MB chunks and create a Document for each chunk?

But if I did that, I would get duplicate search results that are the same.

Comment: your Note entity can't actually be larger than 1MB anyway - the maximum size of a datastore entity is [1MB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/?hl=en&csw=1#Quotas_and_Limits).

Comment: Ah, that's right.  My oversight.